# Whats the name of this path-finding algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

[image]

The pictures show a graph of nodes arranged like a pixel grid with straight rows and columns. Every node (except for the ones on the edge) have 8 edges, which all go to the closest 8 nodes around it. The picture on the right shows an A* search with a simple distance travelled + euclidean distance to goal heuristic.

Now, i say that the path given by the picture on the right isn't good enough. Instead i want a path that you would get if you would connect the start node and the goal node with the shortest possible string. What is the algorithm for getting that called?

Comment: The picture on the left shows a valid path. The picture on the right doesn't. It is not about a specific algorithm then, it is about changing your environment representation (blue dots= walls, no constraint on going from node to node)

Comment: What is the structure of your map (is it even a grid?), how can you walk (teleporting (with euclidean cost) to any node as long as you don't pass through wall?)

Answer (score 3):

Finding Euclidean shortest paths based on a 2D grid discretization of the traversable space can be performed with the [Theta*](http://aigamedev.com/open/tutorials/theta-star-any-angle-paths/) algorithm.

The other (more commonly employed) approach is based on a standard 4-way or 8-way pathfind (the picture on the left), followed by a "string pulling" optimization. The most common algorithm for this is known as the ["Funnel algorithm"](http://ahamnett.blogspot.ie/2012/10/funnel-algorithm.html).

Note that neither of these approaches is guaranteed to produce the globally shortest path. Also, these assume that you're set on representing the world as a grid; if you instead represent it as a set of convex polygons, other algorithms are more appropriate.

Comment: You mention about _other string pulling algorithms that are more appropriate_ for convex polygons; can you please name them? It might be useful.

Comment: @legends2k If your environment can be described as a polygonal decomposition, you can do A* on the faces/edges of the polygons themselves, either using a midpoint heuristic or (if you demand absolute optimality at the cost of hugely increased complexity) Hershberger's algorithm described in "An Optimal Algorithm for Euclidean Shortest Paths in the Plane".

Answer (score 0):

This is a 2D [Euclidean shortest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_shortest_path) problem with polygonal obstacles.

For an algorithmic solution, check these two references:

- Hershberger, John; Suri, Subhash (1999), "An optimal algorithm for Euclidean shortest paths in the plane", SIAM Journal on Computing 28 (6): 2215–2256, doi:10.1137/S0097539795289604.
- Kapoor, S.; Maheshwari, S. N. (1988), "Efficient algorithms for Euclidean shortest path and visibility problems with polygonal obstacles", Proc. 4th ACM Symposium on Computational Geometry, pp. 172–182, doi:10.1145/73393.73411, ISBN 0-89791-270-5.